Oracle: refresh view based on a sql macro table
I have a function that returns a sql macro table A, and another view is created to replicate sql macro table A
package macros
function f1 return varchar2 sql macro(table) is
begin
return q'{select col1, col2 from table1}' 
end;

create view v_A as
select * from macros.f1();

When I updated table1, then the result select * from macros.f1() reflects the changes. But view v_A is not refreshed.
May I ask why the source table and source macro table are updated but the view is not updated?
Thanks for any help.

The reason for having a view as replica of macro table is that I have another merge statement in a procedure which uses information from macro table. When using directly the macro table in merge statement and compiling the package, it returns error. But if I replace the macro table by a view in the procedure, the package can be compiled

The code doesn't look syntactically correct - e.g. it should be SQL_MACRO, not SQL MACRO. Please post your real code.

@FrankSchmitt thanks for your comment. Yes, it's sql_macro. My mistake when writing this question

That seems to work as expected. Please provide a [mcve] that shows the issue occurring. (Maybe you're querying the view in a different session and you haven't committed the changes? Or maybe it's actually a materialised view?)
